# Buffered Reader: read and save certain parts of a line with HashMap (in java?)

Tags: java, file, io, hashmap, bufferedreader

I have a text file that has these two lines:

> **PC** Looks like the killer was panicking and searched for help as soon as he could......
>   **Cupboard** I understand this is quite the scene to stomach for your first mystery

Using BufferedReader, I would like to save the first word (PC for example) as a HashMap key and the following sentence as its value.

I have searched online for the answer to this and I found a question, created by Rumen, that was answered very similarly to what I was looking for. However, they used line.split() which would only work if I had something like:

> **PC** On

as that would save PC as the key and On as the value. Secondly, user funglejunk, another answer used ProcessInformation (as a parameter for list) and I have not learnt about that yet (but will put it on the list!.)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583385/java-bufferedreader-how-to-read-parts-of-a-line) is the answer I am reffering to.

Appreciate all help!

Comment: `split()` would work even on a blank line, let alone on the sample lines you provided. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Line: "PC Looks like the killer was panicking and searched for help as soon as he could......".    After reading - Key: "PC" - Value: "Looks like the killer was panicking and searched for help as soon as he could......"

Comment: User has clearly stated that he wants to "save the first word (PC for example) as a HashMap key"  and then "following sentence as its value"

Comment: You were looking for `string.split(" ", 2)`, to split into first word and remainder, having at most `2` array elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String key = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' '));
String value = line.substring(line.indexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, completely forgot about the whole substring method!